# Trim whitespaces from esql string

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I want to Trim the white-spaces from a string which I am getting from XML file using esql.

I am using trim command but it doesn't seems to work while trimming spaces, whereas if you want to trim something else the Trim() function seems to be working fine .

example

```
Trim(' ' From '  Nitin  ');
```

Result

> Nitin

---

```
Trim('i' From 'Nitin');
```

Result

> Ntn

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE whiteSpace CONSTANT CHARACTER CAST( X'090D0A20' AS CHAR CCSID 1208);
 -- tab, cr, lf, space 
DECLARE input2 CHARACTER 'smith'; 

SET input2 = whiteSpace || input2 || whiteSpace; 
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Top.Out2 = TRIM( whiteSpace FROM input2);
```

output:

```
<Top><Out2>smith</Out2></Top>
```